# How to remove the empty lines in an html file

Tags: visual-studio-code

In the image below there are empty lines before the `head`, `body` and closing `/html` tags and within the `body` tag I want to remove.  How?

[image: html file with empty lines]

Comment: Use `ctrl+h`, set the checkmark for use regular expression, search for `\r\n\r\n` and replace it with `\r\n`. Or manually go to each line and remove it.

Comment: Use delete key? Unclear what you are asking. Asking for key commands, a plugin, etc?

Comment: Use `\n\n*` in the FInd Widget with regex option enabled, replace with `\n`.

Answer (score 1):

- put cursor at end of line with text
- press `Shift-ArrowRight` as many times till cursor at pos 1 selecting all newlines till next text
- `Ctrl+Shift+L` to select all similar parts
- `ArrowRight`
- `Backspace` as much times as needed
- `Esc` to leave multi cursor

Answer (score 0):

According to your screenshot, you can try to reduce the line height to reduce the gaps between two successive lines.

1. Open Settings
2. Type Line height in the search bar
3. Specify your desired line height

And done.

Also you could try reducing your font size which would automatically decrease the line height thus reducing gaps in between successive lines.

[image: Settings section of VS Code editor]

Answer (score 0):

Use `\n\n*` in the Find Widget (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>) with the regex option (`.*`) icon enabled, replace with `\n`.  `Replace All.`

or better change this setting:

```
// List of tags, comma separated, that should have an extra newline before them. `null` defaults to `"head, body, /html"`.
`HTML > Format: Extra Liners`
```

In your `settings.json`:

```
"html.format.extraLiners": ""  // just leave empty
```

Now when you format the html file those empty lines above `head/body/\html` should be removed (select all and Command Palette: `Format Selection`).